# Updating leaflet variable using dajax?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Really, I think this a somewhat easy question for someone with some more experience in javascript programming.

I have a Django app to map some locations using leaflet. I'm using [dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com) for some on mouseover event already I want to integrate some filters using the same library. Problem is, I can't manage to update the map with the filtered data. The template tag `{{ geo_json|safe }};` holds the data the map is initialised with. To clarify, here is my js code from my template

```
var map = L.map('leaflet_map').setView({{zoom|safe}}, 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/439299294ed945808af82774cd1b55a0/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
{
   attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, Imagery &copy; <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
   maxZoom: 18
   }).addTo(map);

var geojsonFeature = {{ geo_json|safe }};


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on('click', function (e) {

          var id = feature.properties.id
          win_str = '/vsoilmap/popup?id=' + id
          window.open(win_str,'mywindow')
      });

      layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {

          var id = feature.properties.id
          win_str = '/vsoilmap/popup?id=' + id
          Dajaxice.VsoilMap.show_vsoil(Dajax.process,{'pk':id})
          });

      layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
          Dajaxice.VsoilMap.hide_vsoil(Dajax.process)
      });

}

var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
            fillColor: "green",
    color: "darkgreen",
    weight: 0.5,
    opacity: 0.8,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};          

var gj = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
               return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    }}).addTo(map);
```

What I'm basically trying to do is to update the variable `geojsonFeature`. If I use the [dajax add_data](http://django-dajax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#assign-selector-attribute-value) method I get the error `Map container is already initialized`. Of course the whole point of using ajax is to NOT load the map again so my question really is: how can I change the content of a variable in `js` without running the whole function again?